# IBM Content Manager OnDemand WEBi - blank login page in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer

The login page of IBM's web interface to its document archive software "Content Manager OnDemand" doesn't load on Internet Explorer 11.

The web application is built on the dojo framework.

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Internet Explorer cannot load binary data from an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX), and some big stylesheets and javascripts are compressed with .gz.

I have worked around this problem successfully by making decompressed copies of these files:

```
./dojo/dojo.js.gz
./dojo/wcdojo.js.gz
./styles/wcdojo.css.gz
```

(all relative to `/opt/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/ondemandwebNode01Cell/wcappservices.ear/wccommonservices.war`)

and then changing the references to them (in files `./webi_js.jsp` and `./pageComponents/printTextNotes.jsp`) to fetch the uncompressed copy instead.

Allowing script debugging turned up the error code [c00ce514](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21900173/385571) which got me in the right direction thanks to some stack overflow questions and answers.